# How Can i Change the Time of ( Special Price To Date ) in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1.4

I can set the sale date of my product but I can't set the time when the sale expires.

[image]

I want my product special price to expire on midnight around 12:01 am. how can i edit that?

Answer (score 0):

calendar widget has to be started with `showsTime` parameter set to `true`. Take a look at `Calendar.setup`

You also have to ensure the way to the database. Take a read of [this Article](http://mydons.com/how-to-show-time-in-magento-date-picker/). It is not perfect, but gives an Idea how to achieve this behaviour.